# Calculate discount price

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make my application to calculate a discount price. This is how I find my discount price, but I have a little problem (logic problem):

```
private void UpdateDiscount(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal actualPrice = 0;
    decimal discount = 0;
    int calculateDiscount = 0;
    int totalDiscount = 0;
    int afterDiscount = 0;
    int totalAfterDiscount = 0;
    int total = 0;

    if (numericTextBox1.TextLength == 6)
    {
        this.numericUpDown2.Enabled = true;

        discount = Convert.ToInt32(this.numericUpDown2.Value);

        calculateDiscount = Convert.ToInt32(discount / 100);

        totalDiscount = calculateDiscount;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.numericTextBox3.Text.ToString()))
        {
            actualPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(this.numericTextBox3.Text);
        }

        else
        {
            numericTextBox3.Text = "";
        }

        afterDiscount = Convert.ToInt32(actualPrice * totalDiscount);
        totalAfterDiscount = Convert.ToInt32(actualPrice);
        total = Convert.ToInt32(totalAfterDiscount - afterDiscount);

        if (numericUpDown2.Value > 0)
        {
            this.numericTextBox6.Text = total.ToString();
        }
    }

    else if (numericTextBox1.TextLength != 6)
    {
        this.numericUpDown2.Enabled = false;

        this.numericUpDown2.Value = 0;
        this.numericTextBox6.Text = "";
    }

    else
    {
        actualPrice = 0;
        discount = 0;
        calculateDiscount = 0;
        totalDiscount = 0;
        afterDiscount = 0;
        totalAfterDiscount = 0;
        total = 0;

        MessageBox.Show("There is no data based on your selection", "Error");
    }
}
```

This is the result, the total after discount still same with the total price, even though I already give it discount value.

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: my bad L.B, i will remove it. Thanks :D
@JohnSaunders: sure, next time i will not do it anymore. Thanks :D

Comment: Take a look here http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/percent/sale_price.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is mostly due to the fact that you're using integers for everything. In particular, these two lines:

```
discount = Convert.ToInt32(this.numericUpDown2.Value);    
calculateDiscount = Convert.ToInt32(discount / 100);
```

When you use 10 for "10%" as the discount, the second line there is actually resulting in a zero. This is because you are doing integer mathematics: integers can only be whole numbers, and when they have a number that is not whole they truncate it. In this case, discount / 100 in your example would be 0.1, which would get truncated to zero.

Instead of using int, I recommend using decimal for all financial transactions. I would replace most of your integer variable types throughout that function with decimal.

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much sir. This is will be my experience when i am doing the same thing again to not using `int` type when dealing with money.

Answer (score 6):

Given

- a price `P` such that `0 <= P`, and
- a discount percentage `D` such that `0 <= D <= 100`

you can compute the discount (markdown) `MD` that needs to be applied as

```
MD = P * (D/100)
```

You can then get the discounted price `DP` as

```
DP = P - MD
```

Given that, this should do you:

```
public static class DecimalHelpers
{
  public static decimal ComputeDiscountedPrice( this decimal originalPrice , decimal percentDiscount )
  {
    // enforce preconditions
    if ( originalPrice   <   0m ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "originalPrice"   , "a price can't be negative!"    ) ;
    if ( percentDiscount <   0m ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "percentDiscount" , "a discount can't be negative!" ) ;
    if ( percentDiscount > 100m ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "percentDiscount" , "a discount can't exceed 100%"  ) ;

    decimal markdown        = Math.Round( originalPrice * ( percentDiscount / 100m) , 2 , MidpointRounding.ToEven ) ;
    decimal discountedPrice = originalPrice - markdown ;

    return discountedPrice ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `int` (or `Convert.ToInt32`) when dealing with *money*.

See this

```
decimal discount = 10;
var calculateDiscount = Convert.ToInt32(discount / 100);
MessageBox.Show(calculateDiscount.ToString());
```

`calculateDiscount` will be `0` because 0.1 will be converted 0.

Comment: why wouldn't we are not all, allowed to use `int` or `Convert.ToInt32` when dealing with money sir? Anyway, thank you to your answer, i will try it

Comment: Because when computers do integer division, something like `10/100` is `0` not `0.1`. When the CPU does integer division, it computes an integer **quotient** and and integer **remainder**, just like you'd do  in elementary school (CPUs are stupid). Usually, the divide instruction will set two registers with the result of the divide instruction: one holding the quotient and one the remainder. High-level languages don't generally give you direct access to the remainder.

Comment: @NicholasCarey It seems you haven't taken the *Digital Design* or *Computer Organization* courses..

Comment: Eh?

In c# and most other high-level languages, when I execute integer division: `int x,y; int q = x / y;` the remainder is chucked, unless you know something I don't. To get the remainder you have to explicitly perform another operation: `int r = x % y;'. It is, of course, possible that the two divide operations will be optimized into one, but it is by no means guaranteed.

Working in assembler, I can execute a single integer divide instruction and get both quotient and remainder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have problems with...

```
calculateDiscount = Convert.ToInt32(discount / 100);
```

Int (Integers) are whole numbers, they will be rounded down. If discount is less than 100 it will always be zero.

Avoid using double or floats for financial transactions as they can produce considerable floating point errors.

Using integers is good, as they are accurate and quick, HOWEVER you MUST always consider how numbers will be rounded, ensure the operands and results are always whole numbers.

If they are not whole numbers use the Decimal structure, which under the covers is comprised of three integers, but three times slower than using integers.

In most cases being 3 times slower than blindingly quick, still ends up being blindingly quick so when in doubt use Decimals.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the Original Price from the Discounted Price and Discount Value. you can use this code

````
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        decimal discountedPrice = 280;
        decimal discount = (decimal)0.20;
        decimal originalPrice = discountedPrice / (decimal)(1-discount);
        Console.WriteLine(originalPrice);
    }
}```
````